# French Long stay Visa for girlfriend

Tags: france

I am joining a French institute as a post-doctoral researcher and would like to take my girlfriend (and soon to be wife) with me. Our marriage date is just 7 days before the date of journey and therefore we have to apply for the visa much earlier than the marriage date. Is it possible to take her with me with a dependent long visa? I can even show the proof for the notice of registry marriage. If yes, is there any lower limit on my bank balance?

Comment: Hi. This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have another site for moving abroad, called [expatriates.se]. It would be better to ask there.

Comment: Why don't you get married earlier?

Comment: Yes. Just register your marriage earlier. You can keep the ceremony on the date you originally planned it.

Comment: can you explain more in an [edit] your question what the concern is about the bank balance please?